# Is Aperture compatible with High Sierra upgrade process?

Tags: macos, aperture

If I update the newest software version to 10.13 and apply all security patches, will it delete my Aperture program?

Comment: Please let us know with an edit what version your aperture is. Aperture 2.0 might fail so we can’t guess which of the several versions you have. I put 10.13 as the latest since a year from now or a week from now, the latest changes.

Answer (score 3):

> *IF* you bought Aperture from the Mac App Store, you should be able to re-download it from there from the Purchases tab, even though it’s no
>   longer available for sale. (However, I never did, so I can’t confirm
>   this.)

I can confirm this is possible to download on High Sierra still and that it is in the Purchases tab.

If you can't find it you may have downloaded it on a different account or it may be hidden, you can unhide purchases from the My Account link.

Comment: For the million dollar question - does it run and open libraries? I know [it used to run to prepare a library for loading things into Photos app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204655). No need to tack this on - I can ask a follow on question if needed. Thanks for confirming this important major item.

Comment: It does work but I stopped using it after several library corruptions, slowness and crashing. It might be that those were related to my library and a drive failure though.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you're going to upgrade to the newest version of Mac OS, the answer is that you *should* be OK, it should not delete Aperture, but it's always best to have a backup whenever you are doing an upgrade, just in case.

*IF* you bought Aperture from the Mac App Store, you should be able to re-download it from there from the Purchases tab, even though it’s no longer available for sale. (However, I never did, so I can’t confirm this.)